# How do I export the data rendered by react component to pdf?

Tags: reactjs, printing, pdf-generation

I have a component view which has images, tables, and list styled with CSS. Is there a legit approach to export/save that view to pdf? `ctrl+p` doesn't really work because it grabs the entire page with navigation etc.
I'm thinking to implement `print` button which will redirect to another "PrintComponentCleanView" and from there do `ctrl+p`. This is a 2 step process. I'm sure there is a better approach to accomplish this. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: You can use a print stylesheet if the use case just involves hiding navigations etc.

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding print styles in your existing stylesheet:

```
@media print
{
  .navbar {
    display: none;
  }
  ...
}
```

Adding a different stylesheet for printing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="style.css">
```

You can then use `window.print();` for opening up the Print dialog.